# reusing nuxt codes in Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, nuxt.js

**Background**

I had been building frontend with nuxt and elixir/phoenix as a backend, with nginx for reverse proxy.

However, to improve the performance, I want to deploy the whole thing in Elixir/Phoenix.

**My Objective**

I want to use my nuxt code in Elixir/Phoenix.

**What I don't understand**

I don't know how to keep the routing, server side rendering, and configulations made in nuxt.config.js.
Although if I get keep the components I made it accessible globally, I can give up on other configulations.

Comment: I don’t get why anything should have changed (maybe except _Phoenix_ should be run on another PORT,) and I completely misunderstand why `nuxt` of whatever frontend should bother. Just get rid of `nginx` and you should be set. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think using this in production, then DONT! :). From my point of view, it is not worth making phoenix app responsible for node.js app. But if you want to run all this during developement as single `mix phx.server` command, then follow below steps.

Create `GenServer` that will start nuxt app and add that genserver to application supervision tree. `assets_path` should be path where your nuxt app `package.json` file is, this `assets_path` does not have to be in your phoenix app

```
    defmodule NuxtServer do
      use GenServer, restart: :permanent
      require Logger

      def start_link(assets_path, opts \\ []) do
        GenServer.start(\__MODULE__, [assets_path], opts)
      end

      def init([assets_path]) do
        # in assets folder package.json should contain under scripts node
        # scripts: {
        #   ...
        #   "nuxt": "nuxt"
        # }
        port = Port.open({:spawn, "npm run nuxt"}, [{:cd, assets_path}])
        ref = Port.monitor(port)
        {:ok, %{port: port, ref: ref, assets_path: assets_path}}
      end

      def handle_info({:DOWN, _, :port, _, _}, %{assets_path: assets_path, ref: ref, port: port}) do
        Logger.error("Nuxt server is down, restarting ...")

        Port.close(port)

        Port.demonitor(ref)
        {:ok, state} = init([assets_path])
        {:noreply, state}
      end

      def handle_info({_prot, {:data, msg}}, s) do
        Logger.debug msg
        {:noreply, s}
      end

      def handle_info(msg, state), do: super(msg, state)
    end
```

then follow instructions how to add reverse proxy in phoenix using e.g. this [lib](https://github.com/slogsdon/elixir-reverse-proxy) if you need to access everything trough phoenix http port.